# typeMismatch on decodable Type when the type is correct

Tags: json, swift, codable, decodable

When I hit my configuration API with Postman I am given the following json response back. In this response the two apiVersion keys are numbers and not strings.

```
{
    "data": {
        "availability": {
            "auth": true,
            "ab": true,
            "cd": true
        },
        "helloWorldConfiguration": {
            "apiKey": "abcefg",
            "rootUrl": "https://foo",
            "apiVersion": 3
        },
        "fooBarConfiguration": {
            "baseUrl": "https://foo",
            "apiVersion": 1,
            "privateApiPath": "",
            "publicApiPath": "dev",
            "tokenPath": ""
        }
    },
    "errors": []
}
```

When I try to decode it it fails with a `typeMismatch` error. When I output the contents of the response, I see the following which looks fine to me.

```
data = {
    availability = {
        auth = 1;
        ab = 1;
        cd = 1;
    };
    helloWorldConfiguration = {
        apiVersion = 1;
        baseUrl = "https://foo";
        privateApiPath = "";
        publicApiPath = dev;
        tokenPath = "";
    };
    fooBarConfiguration = {
        apiKey = abcefg;
        apiVersion = 3;
        rootUrl = "https://foo";
    };
};
errors =     (
);
```

The error given to me indicates that `data.helloWorldConfiguration.apiVersion` is of type string instead of int. We can see from the original HTTP response I get from Postman that's not the case.

> typeMismatch(Swift.Int, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "helloWorldConfiguration", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "apiVersion", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Int but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))
>   21:17:40 ERROR Unable to decode the response data into a model representation.

My model represents those properties as integers so it would appear that it receives the response and considers those numbers to be strings, which they're not.

```
public struct ServerConfiguration: Decodable {
    let availability: AvailabilityConfiguration
    let helloWorldConfiguration: HelloWorldConfiguration
    let fooBarConfiguration: FooBarConfiguration

    init(availability: AvailabilityConfiguration, helloWorldConfiguration: HelloWorldConfiguration, fooBarConfiguration: FloatSinkConfiguration) {
        self.availability = availability
        self.helloWorldConfiguration = helloWorldConfiguration
        self.fooBarConfiguration = fooBarConfiguration
    }
}

public struct FooBarConfiguration: Decodable {
    let baseUrl: String
    let apiVersion: Int
    let privateApiPath: String
    let publicApiPath: String
    let tokenPath: String

    init(baseUrl: String, apiVersion: Int, privateApiPath: String, publicApiPath: String, tokenPath: String) {
        self.baseUrl = baseUrl
        self.apiVersion = apiVersion
        self.privateApiPath = privateApiPath
        self.publicApiPath = publicApiPath
        self.tokenPath = tokenPath
    }
}

public struct AvailabilityConfiguration: Decodable {
    let auth: Bool
    let ab: Bool
    let cd: Bool

    init(auth: Bool, ab: Bool, cd: Bool) {
        self.auth = auth
        self.ab = ab
        self.cd = cd
    }
}

public struct HelloWorldConfiguration: Codable {
    let apiKey: String
    let rootUrl: String
    let apiVersion: Int

    init(apiKey: String, rootUrl: String, apiVersion: Int) {
        self.apiKey = apiKey
        self.rootUrl = rootUrl
        self.apiVersion = apiVersion
    }
}
```

As you can see my `apiVersion` members are both of type integer along with the json response. What am I doing wrong here? I assume what's happening is Swift is considering the numbers in the json string, regardless of how they're actually represented in the json. Is that the case?

### Edit to show utf8 string of Alamofire response data

```
21:44:06 INFO GET: https:foo/configuration
{
    "data" : {
        "availability" : {
            "auth" : true,
            "ab" : true,
            "cb" : true
        },
        "helloWorldConfiguration" : {
            "apiKey" : "abcd",
            "rootUrl" : "https://foo",
            "apiVersion" : "3"
        },
        "fooBarConfiguration" : {
            "baseUrl" : "https://foo",
            "apiVersion" : "1",
            "privateApiPath" : "",
            "publicApiPath" : "dev",
            "tokenPath" : "auth/token"
        }
    },
    "errors" : []
}
```

It would seem that despite the API correctly returning `apiVersion` as a number, Swift is turning it into a string. Am I decoding it incorrectly?

```
func getRoute<TResponseData: Decodable>(route:String, completion: @escaping (TResponseData) -> Void) throws {
    let headers = try! self.getHeaders(contentType: ContentType.json)
    let completeUrl: String = self.getUrl(route: route, requestUrl: nil)
    logger.info("GET: \(completeUrl)")
Alamofire.request(
    completeUrl,
    method: .get,
    parameters: nil,
    encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
    headers: headers)
    .validate()
    .responseJSON { (response) -> Void in
        self.logger.info("GET Response: \(String(describing:response.response?.statusCode))")

        switch response.result {
        case .success(_):
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .custom(Date.toFooBarDate)
            do {
                let result = try decoder.decode(TResponseData.self, from: response.data!)
                completion(result)
            } catch DecodingError.dataCorrupted(let error) {
                self.logger.error(error.underlyingError!)
                return
            } catch {
                print(response.result.value!)
                print(error)
                self.logger.error("Unable to decode the response data into a model representation.")
                return
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please create a **String** from the output and `print` this. The collection type output is ambiguous, because you cannot distinguish `String` and `Int`. And you can delete all initializers in the structs. You get them for free.

Comment: String representation of the Alamofire data provided. It does indeed appear to be a string, despite the API returning it as a number. Why would that be the case and how can I fix that?

Comment: If I print out `po print(response.result.value!)` in the console from the Alamofire response, I see the data correctly. strings are strings and `apiVersion` is a number. I'm confused why the raw data in Alamofire doesn't show it as such

Comment: Updated to show my decoding source in the event that I'm not doing that correctly.

Comment: `apiversion` is not and `Int`. Its `string`. Change it to `String` in your `struct`

Comment: I agree. Why not just accept that it’s a String and proceed? You’re worrying about nothing.

Comment: Amit you’re looking at `apiKey` and not `apiVersion`. The `apiVersion` is an `Int`.

Comment: Matt in this example, maybe so. What if the number was financials, or age that needed numeric math done against it. I’d be taking the json number, turning it into a string, then converting back to an int at a later date. It’s a waste when the API gives me the number in the correct format. You’re being dismissive of a valid question IMO.

Comment: I am successfully able to parse the above json using codable and apiversion as Int. You can see my answer

Comment: In the Alamofire response output `apiVersion` is clearly `String`. **Everything** in double quotes is `String`. So the decoder error message is correct (actually it's always correct  ).

Comment: @vadian yes if you go with alamofire response its string.but I went with the postman response

Comment: then it should not be an issue anymore just go with apiVersion as string and you should be good to go.

Comment: No, simply changing a data type should not be the solution. What if I actually need that to be a number so I ca do math or store it in a local DB as an integer? Hacking together a conversion after the fact is sloppy and a bandaid to the underlying issue of Alamofire’s `data` property having numbers decoded  as strings. As mentioned earlier their `response.result.value` prints it correct though. Perhaps I just convert it to json string before decoding  it.

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger Agreed, that's not a solution , you have to find why Alamofire changes the response.Can you once check with URLSession.May be Alamofire is the culprit(I am afraid if it happens so)

Comment: Alamofire is widely based on `URLSession` and I doubt that Alamofire does a type conversion internally. I agree with matt: *You’re worrying about nothing*. If the decoder wants to decode string, do it. Period.

Comment: @vadian ya may be I am worrying to nothing but this response was for the comment made by "johnathon" that  "No, simply changing..."

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger I tested using Alamofire and URLSession without any issue.In both the cases I am able to parse the json with the structure posted in answer.

Comment: "being dismissive of a valid question" I don't see what the valid part is. The way to know what type this is is to let the decoder tell you. It's telling you it's a String. Everything else you're saying is an illusion.

Comment: My bad, I didn’t realize the struct being `let apiVersion: Int` and the API in Postman bringing back a number was an illusion. I’ll go back to coding 101 and figure out how strongly typed programming is a lie.

Answer (score 0):

I checked in my playground and it seems that everything is working fine.To find the real issue i think you are required to provide the real url from where you are getting json and can be checked with alamofire

```
import Foundation
let json = """
{
"data": {
    "availability": {
        "auth": true,
        "ab": true,
        "cd": true
    },
    "helloWorldConfiguration": {
        "apiKey": "abcefg",
        "rootUrl": "https://foo",
        "apiVersion": 3
    },
    "fooBarConfiguration": {
        "baseUrl": "https://foo",
        "apiVersion": 1,
        "privateApiPath": "",
        "publicApiPath": "dev",
        "tokenPath": ""
    }
},
"errors": []
 }
 """
let data = json.data(using: .utf8)


struct Response : Codable {
let data : Data?
let errors : [String]?
 }
 struct Availability : Codable {
let auth : Bool?
let ab : Bool?
let cd : Bool?
 }

 struct Data : Codable {
let availability : Availability?
let helloWorldConfiguration : HelloWorldConfiguration?
let fooBarConfiguration : FooBarConfiguration?
 }

struct FooBarConfiguration : Codable {
let baseUrl : String?
let apiVersion : Int?
let privateApiPath : String?
let publicApiPath : String?
let tokenPath : String?
}
struct HelloWorldConfiguration : Codable {
let apiKey : String?
let rootUrl : String?
let apiVersion : Int?
}


 let decoder = JSONDecoder()

 let response = try decoder.decode(Response.self, from: data!)
 print(response)
```

And here is the response

Response(data: Optional(__lldb_expr_11.Data(availability: Optional(__lldb_expr_11.Availability(auth: Optional(true), ab: Optional(true), cd: Optional(true))), helloWorldConfiguration: Optional(__lldb_expr_11.HelloWorldConfiguration(apiKey: Optional("abcefg"), rootUrl: Optional("https://foo"), apiVersion: Optional(3))), fooBarConfiguration: Optional(__lldb_expr_11.FooBarConfiguration(baseUrl: Optional("https://foo"), apiVersion: Optional(1), privateApiPath: Optional(""), publicApiPath: Optional("dev"), tokenPath: Optional(""))))), errors: Optional([]))

Comment: Why did you change all good non-optional declarations to bad optional ones?

Comment: Its just for nothing because I don't know what will be optional and what will be definitely  there

Comment: This doesn’t solve my problem unfortunately. I know that my model can parse the Postman response, if Alamofire provides it correct. Alamofire though is not since it’s converting the numbers to string. I can stand-up a temporary public API for you to hit in order to provide an example.  Your example bypasses Alamofire where the weird behavior is occurring.

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger Exactly that's the reason I asked you for the URL

Comment: I have had stood up a temporary API that can be accessed here: https://yjlreb9l9g.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test/configuration You may make a GET request to it with no headers and no request body.

Comment: Ok will check and let you know